# Given Q constraints find the number of binary arrays of N elements

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

You have to find the number of arrays having N binary elements (0/1), that satisfy the Q given constraints. 
The constraints are of the form Li Ri Bi. 
Where if Bi is 0, then it means that the sum of the elements of the sub array between Li and Ri is even. 
If Bi is 1, it means that the sub array has odd sum.

Eg. N is 4 Q is 2. The constraints are 1 3 0 and 3 3 1.
Then the answer is 4, the arrays are {1,0,1,1} {1,0,1,0} {0,1,1,0} {0,1,1,1}.

I am looking for a solution of complexity O((N+Q)log(N+Q)) or better.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? We're not here to solve the problem for you, but rather to help you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: I could only come up with an exponential solution. My approach was to create all possible arrays and check if it satisfies the Q condition.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus This problem is from an active programming contest on codechef.com/MARCH16/PARITREE

Comment: This is the correct URL to the concerned problem www.codechef.com/MARCH16/problems/PARITREE

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You are looking for the number of solutions $(x_1,\ldots,x_N)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the field with two elements) of the system of equations
$$
x_{L_1} + \cdots + x_{R_1} = B_1 \\
\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots \\
x_{L_Q} + \cdots + x_{R_Q} = B_Q
$$
Use linear algebra.

Comment: No further hints will be given.

Comment: I was looking for a solution of the complexity O((N+Q)log(N+Q)) or better. This linear algebra approach wont help. Also, I think your approach is not using the fact that we are given ranges, not just elements. I mean, in all equations, Xi will be always followed by X(i+1).

Comment: Then you probably need to sort something. The other option, dynamic programming, seems too slow for this complexity. If you have a target complexity, though, you should let us know. Don't hide things.

Comment: Yeah, I added the target complexity to the question now. I did try the Dynamic programming solution - Sort the queries based on Ri values. Then traverse the array from 1 to N. When at the index i, DP[i] would tell the number of ways to fill the array till i, such that all the conditions ending before or at i are satisfied. But the problem with this approach is the case - the conditions that begin before or at i and dont end at or before i.

Comment: Well, my solution works in $O(Q^3)$. This is the best I can offer right now.